# Как отловить текущее время воспроизведения в MediaPlayer,

Tags: java, android

Есть

```
MediaPlayer mp1;

mp1 = new MediaPlayer();
    mp1.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0){
            arg0.start(); // воспроизведение
        }
    });
    mp1.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0){
        }
    });
```

Запускаю так:

```
        if (!mp1.isPlaying()) {
        String file_out = NameFileSes;
        load2player(file_out);
        mp1.prepareAsync();
    }
```

Как отслеживать сколько времени прошло от начала воcпроизведения?

Где буду применять: есть массив меток (временные) и когда время воспроизведения достигает определенной метки, совершается действие, например выскакивает Toast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Чтобы проверить на какой отметке проигрывания находиться медиа ряд, есть метод int getCurrentPosition();
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#getCurrentPosition()

2) Касательно вопроса, сколько времени прошло сначала проигрывания -  вы можете циклически опрашивать метод getCurrentPosition() и сверять с массивом ваших меток.

3) По этой ссылке вы сможете найти кусок кода, который можете применить для себя, вместо отображения прогресс бара, ваша логика:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10001044/3438228